# react-bootstrap accordion defaultActiveKey is not opening default active key

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

UPDATE: After some experimentation, I have determined that the problem is that I have some code (see the `useEffect()` section below) which updates the accordion when the `menu` object changes.  On. the first render, `defaultActiveKey` works, but on subsequent re-renders, it does not.

I am using the Accordion control from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/) and can get the basic example from the docs working, but after customizing the code quite a bit, the default accordion no longer opens by... default.  Here's probably the most interesting part of the code:

```
  return (
    <>
      <MenuMobile menuItems={menuItems} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Navbar bg="white" variant="light" expand="lg" fixed="left">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/home">
          <img src={logo} width="113" height="40" alt={siteTitle + " Logo"} />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <NavbarToggler open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />

        <Accordion
          defaultActiveKey={menu.defaultActiveKey}
          className="sidebar-menu"
          data-active={menu.defaultActiveKey}
        >
          {menu.cards.map((card, index) => {
            return (
              <Card key={index}>
                <CustomToggle title={card.title} eventKey={card.eventKey} anchors={card.anchors} />
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={card.eventKey}>
                  <Card.Body>
                    {card.anchors.map((anchor) => (
                      <a href={`#${anchor.href}`} key={anchor.href}>
                        {anchor.text}
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Accordion>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
```

I've outputted the `menu.defaultActiveKey` in a data attribute just to make sure it's getting it right and it is.  I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that I'm generating the child `<Card>` components dynamically but I'm not sure what the fix is?

The entire source code is below if you're interested:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import AccordionContext from "react-bootstrap/AccordionContext";
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import { useAccordionToggle } from "react-bootstrap/AccordionToggle";
import classNames from "classnames";
import queryString from "query-string";

import MenuMobile from "./menuMobile";
import NavbarToggler from "./navbarToggler";
import EduMenus from "../utility/educationMenus";
import logo from "../images/logo-white.svg";

const CustomToggle = ({ title, eventKey, anchors, callback }) => {
  const currentEventKey = useContext(AccordionContext);
  const onClickToggle = useAccordionToggle(eventKey, () => {
    callback(eventKey);
  });
  const isOpen = currentEventKey === eventKey;

  return (
    <div className={classNames("card-header", { open: isOpen })} onClick={onClickToggle}>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      {!!anchors.length && <i className={classNames("fa", { "fa-angle-down": !isOpen }, { "fa-angle-up": isOpen })} />}
    </div>
  );
};

CustomToggle.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  eventKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  anchors: PropTypes.array,
  callback: PropTypes.func,
};

CustomToggle.defaultProps = {
  anchors: [],
  callback: () => null,
};

const DocsNavbar = ({ siteTitle, location }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(EduMenus.default);
  const menuItems = [
    {
      href: "/education/overview",
      text: "Education",
    },
    {
      href: "/home",
      text: "Business",
    },
    {
      href: "/home",
      text: "Travel",
    },
    {
      href: "/home",
      text: "Healthcare",
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!location && location.search !== "") {
      const params = queryString.parse(location.search);
      if (params.menu) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(EduMenus, params.menu)) {
          setMenu(EduMenus[params.menu]);
        } else {
          console.error(`Menu named '${params.menu}' does not exist`);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <MenuMobile menuItems={menuItems} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Navbar bg="white" variant="light" expand="lg" fixed="left">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/home">
          <img src={logo} width="113" height="40" alt={siteTitle + " Logo"} />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <NavbarToggler open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />

        <Accordion
          defaultActiveKey={menu.defaultActiveKey}
          className="sidebar-menu"
          data-active={menu.defaultActiveKey}
        >
          {menu.cards.map((card, index) => {
            return (
              <Card key={index}>
                <CustomToggle title={card.title} eventKey={card.eventKey} anchors={card.anchors} />
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={card.eventKey}>
                  <Card.Body>
                    {card.anchors.map((anchor) => (
                      <a href={`#${anchor.href}`} key={anchor.href}>
                        {anchor.text}
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Accordion>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};

DocsNavbar.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
  location: PropTypes.object,
};

DocsNavbar.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
};

export default DocsNavbar;
```

Comment: I found that even though the defaultActiveKey and eventKey props are strings you need to use string representations of numbers for this to work properly on state changes. If you use event keys like "foo" and "bar" the defaultActiveKey will not work on state changes, instead use "0" and "1". Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I came up with a workaround.  Not sure if this is the best way but it works so I'll put it out there but if someone has a better solution I'm all ears.

Basically, I removed `defaultActiveKey` because it seems like it only works on initial render, and explicitly set the active accordion with `activeKey` and maintain that in state and set that state whenever the menu changes.

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import AccordionContext from "react-bootstrap/AccordionContext";
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import { useAccordionToggle } from "react-bootstrap/AccordionToggle";
import classNames from "classnames";
import queryString from "query-string";

import MenuMobile from "./menuMobile";
import NavbarToggler from "./navbarToggler";
import EduMenus from "../utility/educationMenus";
import logo from "../images/logo-white.svg";

const CustomToggle = ({ title, eventKey, anchors, callback }) => {
  const currentEventKey = useContext(AccordionContext);
  const onClickToggle = useAccordionToggle(eventKey, () => {
    callback(eventKey);
  });
  const isOpen = currentEventKey === eventKey;

  return (
    <div className={classNames("card-header", { open: isOpen })} onClick={onClickToggle}>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      {!!anchors.length && <i className={classNames("fa", { "fa-angle-down": !isOpen }, { "fa-angle-up": isOpen })} />}
    </div>
  );
};

CustomToggle.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  eventKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  anchors: PropTypes.array,
  callback: PropTypes.func,
};

CustomToggle.defaultProps = {
  anchors: [],
  callback: () => null,
};

const DocsNavbar = ({ siteTitle, location }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(EduMenus.default);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(EduMenus.default.defaultActiveKey);

  const menuItems = [
    {
      href: "/education/overview",
      text: "Education",
    },
    {
      href: "/home",
      text: "Business",
    },
    {
      href: "/home",
      text: "Travel",
    },
    {
      href: "/home",
      text: "Healthcare",
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!location && location.search !== "") {
      const params = queryString.parse(location.search);
      if (params.menu) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(EduMenus, params.menu)) {
          setMenu(EduMenus[params.menu]);
          setActive(EduMenus[params.menu].defaultActiveKey);
        } else {
          console.error(`Menu named '${params.menu}' does not exist`);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <MenuMobile menuItems={menuItems} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Navbar bg="white" variant="light" expand="lg" fixed="left">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/home">
          <img src={logo} width="113" height="40" alt={siteTitle + " Logo"} />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <NavbarToggler open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />

        <Accordion activeKey={active} className="sidebar-menu" onSelect={(e) => setActive(e)}>
          {menu.cards.map((card, index) => {
            return (
              <Card key={index}>
                <CustomToggle title={card.title} eventKey={card.eventKey} anchors={card.anchors} />
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={card.eventKey}>
                  <Card.Body>
                    {card.anchors.map((anchor) => (
                      <a href={`#${anchor.href}`} key={anchor.href}>
                        {anchor.text}
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Accordion>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};

DocsNavbar.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
  location: PropTypes.object,
};

DocsNavbar.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
};

export default DocsNavbar;
```

Comment: I like this answer and my values are coming back good but this still leads my accordion in the closed position. this one is weird